# Secure and sure way to clone an identical LUKS External HDD

Tags: encryption, external-hdd, luks, dd, clone

I am using Lubuntu 18.04.

**LUKS such a wonderful SW**  until you get trapped into a mental pain of never-ending loops. And the worst thing is that I do not know where I made a mistake and why that happens in the first place. My working OS under LUKS NEVER MADE ANY PROBLEMS. Furthermore, pcmanfm almost never crashes. As I posted here:

[External Encrypted HDD LUKS Error mounting /dev/dm-3 can't read superblock Will Not Mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268144/external-encrypted-hdd-luks-error-mounting-dev-dm-3-cant-read-superblock-will)

I read a lot about Crypt copy via udisk, gparted, clonezilla, norton ghost,... and so forth. Now I am confused a lot. People are usually saying quite bad things about those SW and you must edit config files first and so on. **The only good and the best solution they say is via dd? Is that correct?**
The snake bit me and now I'm afraid of the lizard!

**How should I perform that on my EXT HDD:**

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 3,7 TiB, 4000787027968 bytes, 7814037164 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt 
Disk identifier: 431C1552-C071-4A68-92A1-7EF6D3E926F3

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type 
/dev/sdc1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3,7T unknown


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-ff7f6d55-7a9c-4e12-a5a7-aa9dfc6f80db: 3,7 TiB, 4000783007744 bytes, 7814029312 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

I burned myself once with dd losing all my data, so... **Is this correct:**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=7814035455 conv=sync,noerror | pv -s 3,7T |sudo dd of=/dev/sdd
```

**And if you have some better solutions to copy sector by sector, cylinder by cylinder VIA TERMINAL OR GUI, just let me know.**

Comment: Sorry. I don't get it. Where did that occur in the message? If that would be the case I would notice. You mean this:"LUKS NEVER MADE ANY PROBLEMS." Till a week ago that was very correct. I'll avoid Caps in the future if this is the case. No hard feelings.

Comment: [Your question had used all caps right in the title](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1268378/1) (among other places) before I edited it. Thank you in advance for keeping this in mind!

Comment: Ahhh... Yea, mea maxima culpa. Sorry, I didn't notice that at all. I presume my caps lock was on... so... Thanks for educating. I will be more careful in the future. Warmest Regards.

Comment: 1. Create an encrypted filesystem on your external HDD; 2. Mount both filesystems; 3. Copy all files from one to the other. Done.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian, it is not possible. **The main hdd is not mountable.** ;-) I was looking for some solutions to copy sector by sector, cylinder by cylinder. How ever that one works great, I know that from my own experience. Probably I didn't explain myself good enough. Thanx again..